# How to work around Firefox adding fetches from iframes to user’s browser history, such that back button doesn’t take user back to where they’d expect?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, fetch-api

I'm running into an issue where I have following setup

1. `top.html` with several `<iframe src="middle.html?id=n">`s (each id is different)
2. `middle.html` itself has an empty `<iframe>` element (no `src`)
3. Each `middle.html` does a `fetch`, then sets its child iframe's src (unrelated to the fetch)

Result:

Every fetch ends up in the user's browser history so if there are 10 iframes on the page, the user needs to press back 10 times to actually go back in the top page.

This issue doesn't happen in Chrome or Safari

I [filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1828286) but I'm trying to find a workaround.

Things I tried

1. I tried using XHR instead of fetch. Same issue
2. I tried posting a message to `top.html`, having it do the fetch and sending a message back. Same issue
3. I tried using `response.arrayBuffer()` instead of `response.text()` with the `fetch` Same issue
4. I tried fetching a binary file (so the Content-Type: header received is not text/html). Same issue

Here's the 4 files

top.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>top</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=1"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=2"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=3"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=4"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=5"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=6"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=7"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=8"></iframe>
    <iframe src="middle.html?id=9"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

middle.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>middle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>middle</p>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <script>
    (async function() {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      const url = `something-to-fetch.html?${params.get('id')}`;
      const req = await fetch(url);
      await req.text();  // not using result

      const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
      iframe.src = 'child.html';
    })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

child.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>child</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    child
  </body>
</html>
```

something-to-fetch.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>this is not important</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    something-to-fetch
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I overlooking a simple workaround?

NOTE: In my actual site, the fetch IS related to what the iframe in `middle.html` shows but that complication is not required to repo the issue.

Comment: @Yogi that's actually different (apparently). This one is about a specific Firefox bug (which is also triggered when using `contentWindow.location.href`).

Comment: @Yogi none of these seem to talk about `fetch`. The current bug is that the history entries are set only if this  call to `fetch` is done.

Comment: Incidental FYI: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7832 is a related HTML spec issue that proposes changing the per-spec back-button behavior to require skipping history entries that have no user interaction.

Comment: @Yogi, your workaround worked and I accepted it since the question was asking for a workaround but I do agree with Kaiido that it also a different question since the issue doesn't happen if you don't fetch.

Comment: Oh!? I must have messed up my tests when I tried the `location` solution then. I'll rerun them in a couple of hours. But if it does indeed work @gman, there is a possibility that the questions are indeed duplicates and that `fetch` is just one of the heuristics they use to not collapse the history (credits to Domenic Denicola for this hypothesis).

Comment: I now see, I used `location.href = ` instead of `location.replace()`, silly me. I also decided to close this question since it actually does ask about the same thing: how to avoid this. The actual trigger doesn't matter much. I still believe that these triggers are very surprising, and I hope the FF bug will shed some light on what triggers they use exactly and hopefully improve their list (personally I'd have expected it to be solely triggered by user interaction but apparently these heuristics are complex, even in Chrome).